# How to show default image if image field is null in kendo grid ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i want to show default image if image field is null.This is my image field code.

```
{ field: "Photo",
title: "Photo",
template: '<img src="#= Photo #" alt="image" width="80px" height="80px" />',
width: 100
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
{
    field: "Photo",
    title: "Photo",
    template: function(dataItem) {
        return kendo.template(
           '<img src="#= Photo #" alt="image" width="80px" height="80px" />'
        )({Photo: dataItem.Photo || 'http://path-to-image'});
    }
    width: 100
}
```

This `dataItem.Proto || 'http://path-to-image'` means if `Photo` is falsy (`null`, `false`, `0`, `''`, `undefined`) then use default path

[Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/EcaVE/2)

Comment: Sorry for late reply.It Worked :) @Alexander

Answer (score 1):

Simple!

```
{
    field: "Photo",
    title: "Photo",
    template: '<img src="#= Photo == null ? "http://exemple.com/pic.jpg" : Photo #" alt="image" width="80px" height="80px" />',
    width: 100
}
```

Comment: Is this possible with kendo listview for php. As I have set the default image but it's not working.